# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) ajax,mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have ajax request that sends data to my controller , it collects value of my dropdown

the error is

```
POST http://localhost:65070/form/create 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

response of error is

```
The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

**UPDATE**
My Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Form</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FormName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FormName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FormName)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MasterID, "MasterModule")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("MasterID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MasterID)
        </div>
        <select id="State" name="state"></select><br />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}
```

My ajax Request

```
$('#State').change(function () {
  var a = $('#State').val();
    $.ajax({
                url: "/form/create",
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'SubID': a },
                success: function (result) {
                    //        console.log(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

My controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Form form, int SubID)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                form.SubId =SubID;
                form.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                form.CreatedBy = 1;
                form.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                form.IsActive = true;
                form.ModifyBy = 1;
                form.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;

                db.Forms.Add(form);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.MasterID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "MasterId", "ModuleName", form.MasterID);
            return View(form);
        }
```

It is giving 500 internal error.. its awkward plz help

Comment: Whats the response of that error?

Comment: response?  in didnt get

Comment: Theres a response with the error... such as 500: no such method Create - something along those lines. Open your Network tab in the console and watch the request.

Comment: path create/form, method post, type text/html.. this is response in red colr

Comment: i update question wwith image see the image @tymeJV

Comment: @JotDhaliwal Can you please update the question with the **text** of the error; that screenshot is tough to view.

Comment: sure @admdrew i am doing

Comment: Click that error...you should see the actual response.

Comment: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.  here is respone

Comment: Looks like you have the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on the `Create()` method. Either remove it or pass the value in your jquery function. And why is the first parameter `Form form`? Your not passing any values so its going to be null.

Comment: How can i pass the value in jquery funtion of antiforgery token >@StephenMuecke

Comment: Form is nothing just takes values of my txt box @StephenMuecke

Comment: You don't really need `form` parameter, since you already post the value of the textbox in the parameter SubID (and it will be null anyway). I'll post answer for the token

Comment: Done man, i have another simple query regading ajax @StephenMuecke,, can you help me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your post method must have the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute. Either remove the attribute or in the view, add the token

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

and pass it back in the ajax function

```
$('#State').change(function () {
  var a = $('#State').val();
  var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
  $.ajax({
    ....
    data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, 'SubID': a },
    ....
```

Note the `form` parameter is not necessary in the action method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(int SubID)
{
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I've been stuck on this for HOURS D:

Comment: this really helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have an example that I have used in my applications. In the controller, you must place

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Verificar(int idempleado, string desde, string hasta)
     {
      ...
     return Json(suiche, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

In the view, I have an ajax function

```
    function Verificar(desde, hasta) {
        var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
        var empleadoId = parseInt($('#empleadoId').val());
        var url = '/Settlements/Verificar';
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": url,
            "method": "POST",
            "data": { __RequestVerificationToken: token, idempleado: empleadoId, desde: desde, hasta: hasta, }
        }
        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $('#mensajefrom').text(null);
                $('#mensajeto').text(null);
            } else {
                $('#mensajefrom').text("There is another settlement with that date range");
                $('#mensajeto').text("There is another settlement with that date range");
            }
        });
    }
```

in the form, I use `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`