# ASP.Net MVC 5 Ajax request on Edit page Error __RequestVerificationToken is not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I created a cascade dropdown using jQuery Ajax and ASP.Net MVC
I have set my ajax request OnChange of dropdown 
here is my code:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Agency_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "bring_projects(this.value,'bring_projects_by_agency','Project_Id')" })
```

The projects DropDown:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Project_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control"})
```

here is my script:

```
function bring_projects(id, funcs, divname) {
var ajax_image = "<img src='./Content/loading.GIF' >";
$('#' + divname).html(ajax_image);
var params = "&agency_id=" + id;
$.ajax({
    url: funcs,
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
})
.done(function (r) {
    $('#' + divname).html(r);
});
```

}

it gives the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

Note:
I am not Submiting the form I Just do ajax request OnChange of DropDown in my Edit page.

Comment: If you look at the generated HTML source of your page you will see there is a hidden input in the form that's auto-generated. You need to include this in your AJAX request as it is used to ensure that the requesting entity is legitimate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [POST 500 (Internal Server Error) ajax,mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574410/post-500-internal-server-error-ajax-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anti-forgery token is a method of preventing [Cross-Site Request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks. When using default MVC methods it has 2 parts to it:

- Anti-forgery token in your view. It usually is used by using html helper `Html.AntiForgeryToken`. This causes hidden input field `__RequestVerificationToken` to be created on a form
- Attribute `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` applied to your controller or action methods.

In your case error indicates that you have `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` on your method, but the form method did not submit the second part - field `__RequestVerificationToken`. In order to fix that you should add a second parameter to your post method:

```
var params = "&agency_id=" + id;
params += params + "&__RequestVerificationToken=" + $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
$.ajax({
    url: funcs,
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
})
```

You can read more about anti forgery token in this [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how this might work.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(string someValue)
    {
        return Json(new { someValue = someValue });
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

<div id="myDiv" data-url="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
    Click me to send an AJAX request to a controller action
    decorated with the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myDiv').submit(function () {
        var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
                __RequestVerificationToken: token, 
                someValue: 'some value' 
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.someValue);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```