# JQuery Post() to Asp.Net MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc5 where I have a view with a group of radio buttons for region and bu.  On change(), I want to grab the selected values and post them to my controller to perform some logic and return the view.  Ultimately I was hoping to use the $.get() but couldn't find any good examples where it was passing the controller params so I decided to create a GET and POST controller.  I want to detect a change() so that I can use a 'class' to detect any change in value for the radio buttons.  Down the road, I'm going to add two date inputs(hoping change() works on them the same way).

Anyhow, I've got everything working up through var url= ...  However, my $.post() doesn't seem to be making a request to the controller so Im hoping someone can point out what I might be doing wrong.

Also, does the data object return key value pairs to the controller?  Did I set that up right?

Thanks!

View Elements;

```
<div id="BusinessUnit" class="radio-inline dashOptions">
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" class="icheck" checked="checked" value="All" name="buRadio"> All</label>
//...more
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" class="icheck" value="1" name="buRadio"> Software</label>
</div>
//...removed the other radio's to hone in on the issue.
```

Script in the View;

```
 $('.dashOptions').change(function () {
        //var startDate = null;
        //var endDate = null;
        var region = $('input:radio[name=regionRadio]:checked').val();
        var bu = $('input:radio[name=buRadio]:checked').val();

        var data = { businessUnit: bu, region: region, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate};
        var url = '@Url.Action("Index")';

        $.post(url,data);            
    });
```

Controller;

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string region, string businessUnit, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
      //...
    }
```

Lastly, how do you secure the post via ajax?  e.g. [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Update 10:22: Here's the JS fiddle example which works.  However, the same solution in my project is not triggering the .Change() function?  https://jsfiddle.net/p191gdzf/1/

Comment: What if any errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: I'm not the best at debugging in the browser but from what I can tell, none...

Comment: Have you tried alerting or console.log(ging) your 'var url' to check that it's got the correct URL in it?

Comment: As for passing the token if you decorate your method with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574410/post-500-internal-server-error-ajax-mvc/25623305#25623305) but if you want to send back all form values including the token, is easiest to just use `var data = $('form').serialize();` (and just bind to your model in the post method)

Comment: Note also that `$.get(..)` and `$.post(..)` will both pass your data to controller methods.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks on both tips!